# Sending Variables to Word Document Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpdoc

There is any way of sending variables to a word document, rename it and make it downloadable from an application in laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [PHPOffice/PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

> A pure PHP library for reading and writing word processing documents

Answer (score 0):

Well using PHPOffice/PHPWord

you can do in laravel 5.2 something like that:

```
  public function descargardoc($id) 
{
  // New Word document
     setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es'); 
     //return $id;
    $data = $this->getData($id);
    $status = $this->getStatus($id);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $fecha_documento = $this->getFecha($data);
    $fecha_ingreso = $this->getFechaIngreso($data); 
    $fecha_inicio_reduc  = $this->getFechaReducJor($data); 

    echo date('H:i:s') , " Create new PhpWord object" , PHP_EOL;
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

    $document = $phpWord->loadTemplate('doc/reduccion_de_jornada.docx');

    //Mapeo de Variables 

    $document->setValue('ciudad', ($data['ciudad']) );   
    $document->setValue('fecha_documento', $fecha_documento );
    $document->setValue('nombre_persona', ($data['nombre_persona']) );
    $document->setValue('apellido1', ($data['apellido1']) ); 
    $document->setValue('apellido2', ($data['apellido2']) );
    $document->setValue('dni', ($data['dni']) );
    $document->setValue('domicilio', ($data['domicilio']) );
    $document->setValue('calle', ($data['calle']) ); 
    $document->setValue('nrocalle', ($data['nrocalle']) );
    $document->setValue('piso', ($data['piso']) );
    $document->setValue('puerta', ($data['puerta']) );
    $document->setValue('codpostal', ($data['codpostal']) );
    $document->setValue('ciudad', ($data['ciudad']) );
    $document->setValue('nombre_empresa', ($data['nombre_empresa']) );
    $document->setValue('fecha_ingreso',  $fecha_ingreso );
    $document->setValue('puesto_trabajo', ($data['puesto_trabajo']) );
    $document->setValue('categoria_profesional', ($data['categoria_profesional']) );
    $document->setValue('porcentaje_reduccion', ($data['porcentaje_reduccion']) );
    $document->setValue('razon_reduccion', ($data['razon_reduccion']) ); 
    $document->setValue('ini_horario_reduc', ($data['ini_horario_reduc']) ); 
    $document->setValue('fin_horario_reduc', ($data['fin_horario_reduc']) ); 
    $document->setValue('fecha_inicio_reduc', $fecha_inicio_reduc  ); 
    $document->setValue('fin_dia_reduc', ($data['fin_dia_reduc']) );
    $document->setValue('preaviso', ($data['preaviso']) );



    $name = 'Doc'."$id".'-'.'ReduJornada'."$date".'.docx';
    echo date('H:i:s'), " Write to Word2007 format", PHP_EOL;
    $document->saveAs($name);
    rename($name, storage_path()."/word/{$name}");
    $file= storage_path(). "/word/{$name}";

    //$file= storage_path(). "/word/{$name}";

    $headers = array(
          //'Content-Type: application/msword',
          'Content-Type: vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
        );

    $response = Response::download($file, $name, $headers);
    ob_end_clean();

    return $response;



}
```

then in your template file you have to declare your variables in this way:

En **${ciudad}**. a **${fecha_documento}**